# While pulling windows docker image from private registry, Docker trying to download some layers from internet

Tags: docker, windows, docker-registry

I created a Windows based docker image (asp.net web project) and pushed it to my private image registry.

when i pull the image from another windows server (offline and there is not a proxy), i'm getting the following error. As you can see the first two lines (system fs layer) tried to download many times, but it couldn't.

If I create an image and push the private registry, why does the pulling process try to download some layers from the internet?

I checked the ip address (204.79.197.219). It belongs to Microsoft.

How to resolve the issue?

Thank you for help

```
4612f6d0b889: Retrying in 1 second
1bd78008c728: Retrying in 1 second
5fd81474115b: Download complete
b887704f8144: Download complete
b0ba1d0b65f3: Download complete
0e8416bc92db: Download complete
3cd07ed78b88: Download complete
14ed468ea106: Download complete
f695358ea9e2: Download complete
5d1118c7c751: Download complete
f66d3542ac00: Download complete
0afb205dafe5: Download complete
4f64ca1251ee: Download complete
3093e4c70a9a: Download complete
93742327496f: Download complete
7602cf05342b: Download complete
3e18c730e090: Download complete
c870f86c0865: Download complete
28442d8cdc02: Download complete
4519d453c4e2: Download complete
8399eeba9588: Download complete
e1d4cea1955e: Download complete
c3ad37fcb432: Download complete
a3b2cb480d5a: Download complete
493303eb4a29: Download complete
1e3cc68c5708: Download complete
0e458143e888: Download complete
d2ca9661d1fb: Download complete
700fd2d72ce3: Download complete
dial tcp 204.79.197.219:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be the reason - https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/

Configure the Docker daemon Either pass the --registry-mirror option when starting dockerd manually, or edit /etc/docker/daemon.json and add the registry-mirrors key and value, to make the change persistent.

More details in the link

Comment: thank you Nathan, i am gonna check the website and im gonna inform about result.

Comment: if some layers are from public repositories (e.g dockerhub), docker always downloads from internet. there are two options

1. we can manually pull  from public repo and tag the image and push to private registery
2. we can use mirroring as Nathon mentioned